# convert this looping structure using LINQ

Tags: c#, asp.net

Can you please let me know how can we convert this looping structure using LINQ?

```
list<Entity> auditlist=retreivedata()\\method to fetch data
foreach (Entity obj in auditList)

    obj.CultSpecificRevisedData = "NULL";
    obj.CultSpecificPublishedData = "NULL";

    if (obj.RevisedData != null && obj.RevisedData != "NULL")
        obj.CultSpecificRevisedData = ConvertToProfileSpecificFormat(Convert.ToDecimal(obj.RevisedData), DecimalSeparator);
    if (obj.PublishedData != null && obj.PublishedData != "NULL")
        obj.CultSpecificPublishedData = ConvertToProfileSpecificFormat(Convert.ToDecimal(obj.PublishedData), DecimalSeparator);

    var yearPart = obj.CalendarYear;
    var monthPart = string.Empty;
    var frequencyName = GetEnglishFrequencyBame(frequencyTypeMasId);
    if (frequencyName == FrequencyType.Monthly)
    {
        monthPart = new DateTime(obj.CalendarYear, GetMonthNumber(obj.Month), 1).ToString("MMM");
        obj.CultSpecificPeriod = monthPart + "-" + yearPart.ToString();
    }
    if (frequencyName == FrequencyType.Quarterly)
    {
      UserMessage = obj.QuarterName;
        obj.CultSpecificPeriod = UserMessage + "-" + yearPart.ToString();
    }
    else if (frequencyName == FrequencyType.BiAnnually)
    {
        UserMessage = obj.SemesterName;
        obj.CultSpecificPeriod = UserMessage + "-" + yearPart.ToString();
    }
    else
    {
        obj.CultSpecificPeriod = yearPart.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Why would you need to do this? LINQ is a powerful programmer's companion, but it can't fix all problems in the world.

Comment: why do you want to convert it?

Comment: and what is `UserMessage`?

Comment: where does `frequencyTypeMasId` come from?

Comment: There are a number of things you can improve in this code and inappropriate use of Linq will not make them better.

Comment: Are you sure you want to use the string `"NULL"` like this?

Comment: records are retrieved being retrieved from the database then runnnig foreach loop on the retrieved data which is taking more than  2 min.can you let me know if there is any way to optimize it?

Comment: is that 2 mins to retrieve the data, to run the loop or for both combined? How many rows?

Comment: 13k rows.2 mins to run the loop.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you *don't* try to change this to use LINQ:

1) It's modifying objects. That's not what LINQ is designed for. It's designed for *querying*.

2) There's a lot of conditional logic here - not just "set X to Y or Z based on some condition" but "maybe set X, but maybe not". Again, that's really not a good fit for LINQ.

I *would* suggest trying to extract some of the functionality into small methods - the part dealing with the frequency names could certainly be expressed more cleanly, quite possibly with a switch, and extracting the common functionality - but that's not a matter for converting to LINQ, necessarily.

Comment: @Jodrell: Why have you left these comments on my answer? They would be more appropriate on the *question*.

Comment: records are retrieved being retrieved from the database then runnnig foreach loop on the retrieved data which is taking more than 2 min.can you let me know if there is any way to optimize it?

Comment: @user2027720: Well the first thing you need to do is work out where the time is going. We can't do that for you. Is it taking a long time to fetch the data, or is it actually running over the retrieved data which is taking the time? Is it performing *lots* of queries, because you haven't included enough data in the original query? All kinds of details which we can't help you with.

Comment: running over the retrieved data  is taking the time..its taking more than 2 mins to run over 13k records

Comment: @user2027720: Well you need to work out where the time is going. Again, there's not a lot we can do to help you with that, given the information you've provided. You should definitely check whether extra queries are being made implicitly though.

Answer (score 0):

For what its worth, you probably want code a little more like this. I hope this helps in some way.

```
foreach (var e in retreivedata())
{
    e.CultSpecificRevisedData = null;
    e.CultSpecificPublishedData = null;

    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(e.RevisedData))
    {
        e.CultSpecificRevisedData = ConvertToProfileSpecificFormat(
            Convert.ToDecimal(e.RevisedData),
            DecimalSeparator);
    }

    if (!string.IsNullOrWhitespace(e.PublishedData))
    {
        e.CultSpecificPublishedData = ConvertToProfileSpecificFormat(
            Convert.ToDecimal(e.PublishedData),
            DecimalSeparator);
    }

    switch (GetEnglishFrequencyBame(frequencyTypeMasId))
    {
        case FrequencyType.Monthly:
            var f = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat;
            obj.CultSpecificPeriod = string.Format(
                "{0}-{1}",
                f.GetAbbreviatedMonthName(GetMonthNumber(e.Month)),
                e.CalendarYear);
            break;

        case FrequencyType.Quarterly:            
            UserMessage = e.QuarterName;
            e.CultSpecificPeriod = string.Format(
                "{0}-{1}",
                e.QuarterName,
                e.CalendarYear)
            break;

        case FrequencyType.BiAnnually:
            UserMessage = e.SemesterName;
            e.CultSpecificPeriod = string.Format(
                "{0}-{1}",
                e.SemesterName,
                e.CalendarYear)
            break;

        default:
            obj.CultSpecificPeriod = e.CalendarYear.ToString();
    }
}
```